# vlookup on text field using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I need to use vlookup functionality in pandas.

`DataFrame 2:` (FEED_NAME has no duplicate rows)

```
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
| FEED_NAME |        Name        |       Source        |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
| DMSN      | DMSN_YYYYMMDD.txt  | Main hub            |
| PCSUS     | PCSUS_YYYYMMDD.txt | Basement            |
| DAMJ      | DAMJ_YYYYMMDD.txt  | Effiel Tower router |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

`DataFrame 1:`

```
+-------------+
| SYSTEM_NAME |
+-------------+
| DMSN        |
| PCSUS       |
| DAMJ        |
| :           |
| :           |
+-------------+
```

DataFrame 1 contains lot more number of rows. It is acutally a column in much larger table. I need to merger df1 with df2 to make it look like:

```
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM_NAME |        Name        |       Source        |
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| DMSN        | DMSN_YYYYMMDD.txt  | Main Hub            |
| PCSUS       | PCSUS_YYYYMMDD.txt | Basement            |
| DAMJ        | DAMJ_YYYYMMDD.txt  | Eiffel Tower router |
| :           |                    |                     |
| :           |                    |                     |
+-------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

in excel I just would have done VLOOKUP(,,1,TRUE) and then copied the same across all cells.

I have tried various combinations with merge and join but I keep getting `KeyError:'SYSTEM_NAME'`

Code:

```
_df1 = df1[["SYSTEM_NAME"]]
_df2 = df2[['FEED_NAME','Name','Source']]
_df2.rename(columns = {'FEED_NAME':"SYSTEM_NAME"})
_df3 = pd.merge(_df1,_df2,how='left',on='SYSTEM_NAME')
_df3.head()
```

Comment: reset your index on your dataframes with `_df1.reset_index`and `_df2.reset_index`this should work

Comment: Can you do a print(_df2.info()) to ensure the column is being properly renamed after applying `rename` because Pandas documentation states that labels not contained in a dict / Series will be left as is. Otherwise, use this: `_df2.rename(columns = {'FEED_NAME':"SYSTEM_NAME"}, errors="raise")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You missed the `inplace=True` argument** in the line `_df2.rename(columns = {'FEED_NAME':"SYSTEM_NAME"})` so the `_df2` columns name haven't changed. Try this instead :

```
_df1 = df1[["SYSTEM_NAME"]]
_df2 = df2[['FEED_NAME','Name','Source']]
_df2.rename(columns = {'FEED_NAME':"SYSTEM_NAME"}, inplace=True)
_df3 = pd.merge(_df1,_df2,how='left',on='SYSTEM_NAME')
_df3.head()
```